# Buttons are not displaying in ipad 6.0.1 version

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

I am creating a web app using html5 and jquery. It runs fine in all the versions of ipad.
The problem is with version 6.0.1.

I am changing buttons opacity based on some condition. But sometimes buttons are not displaying at all. Here is my code snippet. Please provide some ideas.

```
var isenabled='true';

if(isenabled){
 $('#abc').children().find('a').fadeTo('fast', 1);}
else
 $('#abc').children().find('a').css('opacity', '0.5');
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

```
$('#abc').children().find('a')
```

The above snippet will return all the immediate children of the element with ID "abc" and then find all the descendent anchor elements of those children. So it would not find an immediate child of the "abc" element that was an anchor. Perhaps that was your intention. Alternatively just change it to the following instead

```
$('#abc a')
```

Secondly, I suspect isenabled will always evaluate to true if you continue to assign strings to it. i.e.

```
'true' == true
```

and

```
'false' == true
```

In-fact any non-empty string is always true. Either assign isenabled to the boolean value itself, or compare it to the string 'true' in your if statement.

Not sure if that answers your question unfortunately, but it might help.